# How to check file types of multiple files using "file"

Tags: file, unix, terminal, find

I'm solving this wargame challenge:

http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit5.html

where you have a directory with multiple files, one of which holds the password to the next level. To find the hidded password, you need to find the only file with text in it(the other ones have a file type "data").

I checked the contents of the files with the "file" command and I found the password but I began to wonder how can I do it with one command. I tried using `find` but I can't get it to work.

Question: How can I pipe the output of `find` into `file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file` with multiple arguments:

```
file file1 file2
```

So you can create a `find` statement looking for your desired files and then use the expression:

```
file $(find ... your_condition ...)
```

But probably the best way is to use `-exec` to perform an action on the found results:

```
find ... -exec file {} +
```

this performs the `find` and executes the `file` command on the result list.

Comment: You are welcome :) By the way, just wondering: is this game open? I went through the first steps and it looks promising, but I don't want to enter where I am not invited!

Comment: What do you mean by open? If you mean open to anybody, I think it is. I started from Bandit because my wargame skills are very basic but there are options for advanced players.

Comment: I mean: can I participate?

Comment: `find ... -exec file {} \;` is definitely much better/safer than `file $(find ... )`. Would be even better with a `+` instead of `\;`

Comment: @BroSlow indeed. With `+` it just executes the command once. Updating, thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui Of course you can. It is completely open :)